# Executing INSERT command into LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have created a local Service-Based database and I'm trying to insert data to it with an `INSERT` statement:

```
public void InsertRule(Rule r)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RulesDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO TblRules (From, To, ExecutablePath) VALUES (@From, @To, @ExecutablePath");

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@From",SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@From"].Value = r.From;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@To",SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@To"].Value = r.To;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExecutablePath",SqlDbType.Text);
    cmd.Parameters["@ExecutablePath"].Value = r.ExecutablePath;

    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

I'm getting a `SqlException`:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "@ExecutablePath)" at the end

Comment: `FROM` is a SQL Server reserved keyword and **should NOT** be used as a column name! If you can't change it, you need to put it into square brackets: `[From]` as the column name

Comment: Thanks, that works. but now when i execute this code, it doesnt seems like it updated the database with the new info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` is SQL keywoard, therefore you can't use it in a statement. You should escape it using square brackets `[From]`. That's what the error is about

That means you need to change this line

```
cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO TblRules (From, To, ExecutablePath) VALUES (@From, @To, @ExecutablePath");
```

into

```
cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO TblRules ([From], To, ExecutablePath) VALUES (@From, @To, @executablePath);
```